# Does a Windows 10 endpoint check software installations for malware if they are installed through GPO / SCCM / Software Center?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, windows-10

I'm trying to get a view on what extra security checks our packaging team could do when they download a potentially infected installer from the web before they package an MSI or EXE (assuming that the software vendor didn't provide a checksum or the staff member from the packaging team omitted to check it). By nature, these installers are run with administrative privileges, increasing the chances of exploitation.

I was wondering to what extent an infected installer would fly under the radar if it is downloaded to a SCCM server and packaged there for distribution to clients. If the installer is never run on any system before being deployed, will malware detection on the endpoint be triggered upon installation?

As Windows Defender Smartscreen only kicks in when you actually run the installer (verified by downloading https://demo.smartscreen.msft.net/known/knownmalicious.exe), how is that handled when a software installation is done silently through a GPO / Software Center? Does the packaging process do some sort of a "dry-run" of the executable before packaging it? (checking publisher certificates, perform a virusscan, try to run it and see if SmartScreen goes off, ...) or is it assumed that the person performing the packaging does this manually?

Any and all input and/or links to resources are highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of waiting for the application getting deployed by SCCM or GPO you should at least apply the below Security measures:

1) Monitor any new application get deployed
2) Monitor accounts that have privileged permission which is used by SCCM
3) Monitor SCCM or AD login attempts 
4) Not allow any application to be deployed unless it get approved by Security team
4) For RDP apply MFA

There is also many more, and regarding AV's it will check the signatures once the file land on the hard disk for signatures.
but bear in mind that there is alot of application that can harm your environment that are not detectable by old AV's since they write on Memory sections like fileless malwares and many more so take proactive measures before anything get deployed in your environment.